# xslt copy of attribute from wrong element

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm using this template:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xpath-default-namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:uuid="http://uuid.util.java"
               exclude-result-prefixes="uuid">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="changeSet[createTable]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="createTable"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::createTable)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="createTable/@remarks">
            <xsl:element name="changeSet">
                <xsl:attribute name="id" select="uuid:new-uuid()"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="author">system</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="setTableRemarks">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="createTable//(@tableName,@remarks)" />
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:for-each select="createTable/column[@remarks]">
                    <xsl:element name="setColumnRemarks">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="../@tableName" />
                        <xsl:attribute name="columnName" select="@name"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@remarks"/>

                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="createTable/@remarks"/>
    <xsl:template match="createTable/column/@remarks"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

to transform xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="system (generated)" id="1538720867962-1">
        <createTable remarks="Journal event detail attribute mapping" tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP">
            <column name="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID" remarks="Journal event type identifier" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
            </column>
            <column name="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID" remarks="Journal event detail attribute identifier" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
            </column>
            <column name="LISTORDER" remarks="Order in list" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I expect that result will be:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
   <changeSet author="system (generated)" id="1538720867962-1">
      <createTable tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP">
         <column name="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
         </column>
         <column name="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
         </column>
         <column name="LISTORDER" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
         </column>
      </createTable>
   </changeSet>
   <changeSet id="c85f187d-f917-4948-8c48-7b1a132dd79e" author="system">
      <setTableRemarks remarks="Journal event detail attribute mapping" tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID"
                        remarks="Journal event type identifier"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID"
                        remarks="Journal event detail attribute identifier"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="LISTORDER"
                        remarks="Order in list"/>
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

but instead of that I get this:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
   <changeSet author="system (generated)" id="1538720867962-1">
      <createTable tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP">
         <column name="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
         </column>
         <column name="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK$AS_JOURNALEVENTDETATTRMAP"/>
         </column>
         <column name="LISTORDER" type="NUMBER(9, 0)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
         </column>
      </createTable>
   </changeSet>
   <changeSet id="c85f187d-f917-4948-8c48-7b1a132dd79e" author="system">
      <setTableRemarks remarks="Order in list" tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="JOURNALEVENTTYPEID"
                        remarks="Journal event type identifier"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRID"
                        remarks="Journal event detail attribute identifier"/>
      <setColumnRemarks tableName="AS_JOURNALEVENTDETAILATTRMAP"
                        columnName="LISTORDER"
                        remarks="Order in list"/>
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

note: the problem is in element setTableRemarks and attribute remarks. It's coppied from another element not from createTable as I guess it should be. Is something in my template wrong or is there another problem?

saxon library used for this is `9.8.0-14` I also tried with `9.9.0-1` but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT in it, rather than an external link which could disappear in future? Thank you!

Comment: sure, added xslt to the top.

Comment: I guess that my problem is in `<xsl:copy-of select="createTable//(@tableName,@remarks)" />` where I have dobule slash instead of single slash. Can you please explain what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="createTable//(@tableName,@remarks)" />
```

Do this...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="createTable/(@tableName,@remarks)" />
```

Using `//` is shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` and so is going to search all descendant nodes of `createTable`, not just the node itself. As this will select multiple attributes with the same name, only the last one will be copied (as adding an attribute to a node where an existing one with the same name already exists should replace it).

Comment: People sometimes use "//" as "magic fairy dust", as in "I don't know what it means but it usually seems to work". Thanks for providing a classic example of why that's not a good idea.